# Why I keep getting Argument of type 'ThunkAction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I'm having a problem with Typescript using Redux Thunk. I keep getting TS error `Argument of type 'ThunkAction<void, EmptyObject & { items: ItemsState; }, unknown, AnyAction>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.` even when I followed official docs to use and alternative Dispatch function https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#use-typed-hooks-in-components
I know there's a Redux Toolkit package available but I don't want to use it.

I've got action defined like this:

```
export const fetchData =
  (): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, AnyAction> => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST,
    });
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(API_URL);
      dispatch({
        type: SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: FAILURE,
        payload: error,
      });
    }
  };
```

and then I use it in my index.tsx file:

```
  import { useAppDispatch } from './hooks';

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData());
  }, []);
```

Obviously `useAppDispatch` is a function that I defined:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import type { AppDispatch } from '../store';

type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch;
export const useAppDispatch: DispatchFunc = useDispatch;
```

and in store I've got type definition:

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    __REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__?: typeof compose;
  }
}

const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
```

Still getting an error above from TS. Tried restarting VS Code but nothing worked. Adding TS config for visiblity:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

EDIT:
Maybe there's a problem with my Thunk function? Posting one of the thunk functions Im using:

```
export const fetchData =
  (): ThunkAction<void, RootState, unknown, AnyAction> => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.FETCH_DATA,
    });
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(API_URL);
      dispatch(actions.loadSuccess(res.data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(actions.loadError(error));
    }
  };
```

Actions.ts

```
const loadSuccess = (payload: TournamentType[]) => ({
  type: actionTypes.FETCH_SUCCESS,
  payload,
});

const loadError= (error: unknown) => ({
  type: actionTypes.FETCH_ERROR,
  payload: error,
});
```

Comment: Can't reproduce it, works fine for me. Please show us where the `AnyAction` and `ThunkAction` types come from

Comment: While it's not directly related, note that you _should_ be using our official Redux Toolkit package to write your Redux logic - it will drastically simplify the code you've shown there: https://redux.js.org/usage/migrating-to-modern-redux

Comment: Here are my imports
`import { AnyAction } from 'redux';`
`import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';`

Comment: Thank you @markerikson for advice. Yeah it would be easier but I wanted to make it without using the Toolkit package for now.

Comment: @Ivelios can I ask _why_ ?  We specifically want _everyone_ who uses Redux at all to write that code using Redux Toolkit.